# Need validation in MDB inputs

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, mdbootstrap

I using MDB package. I have login page. I need validation for the page

```
 <MDBValidation className='row g-3' isValidated>
              <MDBValidationItem >
                <MDBInput
                  wrapperClass='mb-4'
                  label='Email address'
                  id='validationCustom01'
                  type='email'
                  value={formValue.email}
                  name='email'
                  required
                  onChange={onChange}
                  autoComplete='off' />
              </MDBValidationItem>
              <MDBValidationItem >
                <MDBInput
                  wrapperClass='mb-4'
                  label='Password'
                  id='validationCustom02'
                  type='password'
                  value={formValue.password}
                  name='password'
                  required
                  onChange={onChange}
                  autoComplete='off' />
              </MDBValidationItem>
           

            <div className="text-center pt-1 mb-5 pb-1">
              <MDBBtn className="mb-4 w-100 gradient-custom-2" type='submit' onClick={() => { alert("Successfully Logged in") }}>Sign in</MDBBtn>
 </MDBValidation>
```

I wrote the code. But doesn't works fine as I expected. Even if i don't enter the password I can get the success alert on the submit button click. I want to works it fine as antd form. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Could you share a sample executable of your code in `codesandbox`?

Comment: @Majid I used to follow this, https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/forms/validation/

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is right. but in onsubmit function you have to add below codes to validate

```
if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
        event.target.reportValidity();
        event.target.className += " was-validated";
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
```

It will restrict the code execution if you have empty required fields.

For custom errors you can use **MDBValidationItem** component. it having property called **feedback** where you can mention your error text